# Line Integral. Vector field. Parametrization

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

- ###### **Let´s say we want to find the circumferences of the plane $C$ that make the line integral $\int_C y^2dx + x^2dy$ worth zero.**

***My attempt***:

The vector field given is: $\mathbf{F}(x,y)=(y^2,x^2)$. The first thing I try to do is find a parametrization for the path, but I am not sure whether I am looking for the parametrization of a general circumference centered at $(a,b)$ with radius $R$:

$\mathbf{r}(t)=(a+R \cdot \cos(t),b+R \cdot\sin(t))$ where $0 \leq t \le 2\pi$

$\mathbf{r'}(t)=(-R\sin(t),R\cos(t))$

Being that the case:

$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t))=\mathbf{F}(x(t),y(t))=((b+R \sin(t))^2,(a+R\cos(t))^2$) obtaining:

$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t))\cdot\mathbf{r'}(t)= ((b+R \cdot \sin(t))^2,(a+R \cdot\cos(t))^2) \cdot (-R\sin(t),R\cos(t)) $

Finally, we must impose:
$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t))\cdot\mathbf{r'}(t) dt =0.$

However, we aim to find three parameters using only one condition. Perhaps, while calculating the integral we are left with fewer unknowns, but, despite that, the calculation part is still hard.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but there is a simpler way.

Let $D$ be the disc such that $\partial D=C$, then by [Green's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem),
$$\int_C y^2dx + x^2dy=\iint_D(2x-2y)dx dy=2|D|(\bar{x}-\bar{y})$$
where $(\bar{x},\bar{y})=(a,b)$ is the centroid of $D$ and $|D|=\pi R^2$ is its area.
Hence the line integral is zero if and only if $a=b$. The value of $R$ is irrelevant.

Notice that from your last line, after a bit of work, we obtain the same result
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t))\cdot\mathbf{r'}(t) dt 
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}((b+R\sin(t))^2,(a+R\cos(t))^2) \cdot (-R\sin(t),R\cos(t))dt\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}(-b^2R\sin(t)-2bR^2\sin^2(t)-R^3\sin^3(t))dt\\
&\qquad+\int_0^{2\pi}(a^2R\cos(t)+2aR^2\cos^2(t)+R^3\cos^3(t))dt\\
&=0-2bR^2\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(t)dt+0+0+2aR^2\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2(t)dt+0\\
&=2\pi R^2(a-b).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Very true! I didn´t think about using Green´s Theorem. This is definitely the simple way I was looking for. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you for completing my approach. I now can see how the exercise can be addressed from these two different angles perfectly well.

Comment: @Mvg You are welcome!